# Recover Azure Mobile Service Source Control Credentials

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I was trying to use source control for my mobile services. But it prompts me to enter a username and password for deployment. I don't actually remember if I had ever set one before. And I couldn't find a way to reset this. It appears to be a simple task for web apps but I can't figure out how to do this in AMS. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Apparently this is the same deployment credential used for other Azure services like Web apps as well. So I was able to reset it on webapps. But this is rather annoying because the Azure Mobile Services documentation points to an option that doesn't exists in this article if you had previously use deployments on other services. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/